# Google Sheets: How do I "ImportDATA" or "importRANGE" from single cell into merged cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet that has the first three columns filled with 2-cell high merged cells down to row 42.

Example:
[image]

I would like to import data from another sheet (rows A4:A23) and have that data populate into the merged cells A3-4:A41-42.  Is it possible?

This function brings the information in, but it does not display correctly in the merged cells.

```
=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheetIdentifier","TabName!A4:A23")
```

The idea is to have the player and their strength numbers in columns `A:C` and then have their two assignments in the un-merged rows in columns `D:F`.

Thanks for any assistance you can give.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some mistake in the syntax

Please try the following

```
=IMPORTRANGE("JUST_THE_SHEET_ID_HERE","TabName!A4:A23")
```

*(If still facing issues edit your question, share some data, the expected results and let us know.)*